# How to make an iframe the value for href in <a> tag?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

How to make an iframe the href of  tag and open the iframe in a new tab? I don't want any iframe to show up before the link is clicked. If this is not possible, then please give me other code that shows a link, but when someone clicks on it, it opens an iframe on a new tab, with a src value to that iframe.

Comment: I am not sure what you need. Do you have some code example what you have now? Do you really mean `<iframe/>` or you mean just new tab by using `target="_blank"` in your `<a>` tag?

Comment: Please provide us with some code so we can try to help you out, SO is not a code providing service

Comment: If you are opening a new tab, why use an iframe? Anyway, please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and what types of question are [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for the site

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit unclear, so my anwser isn't completed when it comes to handling the iframe on the newly opened tab, but this should be the code you are looking for:

```js
function openNew(src){
  window.open(
    'yournewpage.php?iframesrc=' + src,
    '_blank' // <- This is what makes it open in a new window.
  );
}
```

```css
#color{
  background:green;
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
}
```

```html
<h3>
this is your link, and when clicked on we run javascript opening a new page(_blank) and we add any type of link in the onclick and pass it into the link on the new tab, then you can grab that src from the link and add it into a new iframe on the new tab
</h3>
<div id="color" onclick="openNew('https://stackoverflow.com')">
<h3>
link
</h3>
</div>
```